# What's the difference between USE and FORCE in the index hints?

Tags: mysql, sql

As you know, a query uses just *one* index per table. Therefore there is some index hints which let us to tell the query to use which index. [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html) is the documentation for that.

There is three index hints:

- `USE`
- `IGNORE`
- `FORCE`

Well I cannot understand what's the difference between `USE` and `FORCE`. They seem identical to me. Anybody knows what's their different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The USE INDEX (index_list) hint tells MySQL to use only one of the named indexes to find rows in the table.
>
> The FORCE INDEX hint acts like USE INDEX (index_list), with the addition that a table scan is assumed to be very expensive. In other words, a table scan is used only if there is no way to use one of the named indexes to find rows in the table.

[From the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html)

So USE INDEX makes the DB use only specific indexes to make the search and if necessary a table scan *.

FORCE INDEX does the same but makes sure a table scan is used only if really, really necessary.

<sub>* A *table scan* is reading table data without indexes</sub>

Comment: Ok thank you .. upvote.. Just "a table scan" is  "an index" ?

Comment: Ah I see. You said the different is this: *"but makes sure a table scan is used only if really, really necessary."*. Also you said the same for `USE` index: *"and if necessary a table scan"*. So what's the different?

Comment: The difference is that FORCE INDEX tries to avoid table scans more than USE INDEX. Normally table scans take a lot of time.